# Avoid escaping & in &amp;

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to convert some xml files. Its a 3 pass process.

on the first pass I use str_replace to escape the ampersand

```
$cleanChild = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $child);
```

the problem comes on the second pass (and third), If I dont escape since it was escaped in the first pass i get a `unterminated entity reference` warning.

if I do escape again, it turns `&amp;` into `&amp;amp;` on the first pass and `&amp;amp;amp;` on the third.

To workaround this I am changing `&amp;` to `&` and then back to `&amp;`

```
$newChild = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $child);
$newChild = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $newChild);
```

This works but is there anyway to avoid this ?

ps. using CDATA is not an option.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Found the problem, refer to [PHP's SimpleXML & Escaping that Ampersand](http://www.sagetree.net/news/simplexml)

I am adding using `addChild()`

Instead of

`$xml->addChild('detail', $newChild);`

Did this

`$xml->detail = $newChild;`

and I don't need to escape since simplexml encodes it when using the assignment operator

Comment: What do you want to convert into what?

Comment: Why not only do the str_replace on the third pass?

Comment: because I have to save the result of every pass. And if I dont escape it gives me a warning and ignores all the text remaining text in that element containing the &

Comment: @Akash Okay, so only do it on the first one.

Comment: @DaveRandom I have to save it at every pass. Unless I escape, it doesnt save all the data in that element

Comment: Technically XML isn't HTML but htmlspecialchars only converts those "problem" characters that are common to both HTML and XML anyway... so why not use something like: `htmlspecialchars($child, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);` (switch off double encoding - PHP 5.2+)

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure that there is a better way, and you should only really need to escape these once, this line will convert all occurences of `&` in a string to `&amp;`, unless it is followed by `amp;`.

```
$str = preg_replace('/&(?!amp;)/','&amp;', $str);
```

Comment: The first pass was done few days ago it converted the `&` into `&amp;` which is what was expected. On the second pass it complains about the `&amp;` and wont save properly unless i change it back and forth to `&` and then `&amp;`

Comment: and it only does that for `&amp;` and not `&lt;` or `&gt;`